# Strange result of executing database statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a table with 9000 items and for test reasons i renamed one object's name into "LOL". Now I want to show me all data records which don't match that string. So, the result has to be 8999 but I only get 620 which is really strange.

Query:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM [xxx] WHERE xxx.name = "LOL";
>>Result 1
SELECT Count(*) FROM [xxx] WHERE xxx.name <> "LOL";
>>Result 620
```

It's a MS Access DB and the datatype of that column is short text.

I really don't get it, why there are so many data records filtered out. It seems like that the NOT EQUAL Operator doesn't work in Access DB. NOT LIKE causes the same result.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the data. How many rows are returned without the count aggregation "select * from xxx where name <> 'LOL' "?

Comment: Also 620 data records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the other columns with null values ?

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM [xxx] WHERE xxx.name is null or xxx.name <> "LOL";
```

Comment: Well it works! That was the reason. Can you explain the reason behind this? Because i thought with <> i would also filter null values.

Comment: Yes your logic is right. But DBMS do not manage to compare null values with the string and don't add them to the count, so need to add that condition.